# unable to install npm package from github

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I use a workspace into my app

```
  "workspaces": [
    "firstapp/web",
    "secondapp"
   ]
```

Into second app, into package.json I get into dependencies:

```
"anotherapp": "https://github.com/me/anotherapp.git",
```

From root I run `yarn workspaces foreach -Apt install` everething is ok

I run `yarn workspaces foreach -Apt build` but get `Cannot find module 'anotherapp' or its corresponding type declarations.`

I get this both in CI and during dev (on local)

I don't know what is wrong

If I import my anotherapp as `"anotherapp": "../anotherapp"` on local it's working.
So I don't know how to fix it.

**EDIT**: the concerned repo: https://github.com/Ludea/lucle-plugins
secondapp, where I import a package from GH is speedupdate
And the app imported from GH is https://github.com/Ludea/mui-file-dropzone

Comment: Unfortunately would probably need to see the structure of your repo to be able to help you with this.

Comment: I edit my post with relevant link